# Slide Toggle from Left to Right

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I'm trying to slide a div from left to right, e.g. the structure would be like the following;

A link is placed on the left corner of a page (having a html table hidden with `display: none` css property), when this link clicked the hidden table slides from left to right.

Here is the code I'm trying;

### HTML:

```
    <div id="latest_threads_link">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="latest_threads_click"><img src="images/latest_threads.png" alt="Latest Threads" title="Click Here to see latest threads of this section."></a>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="'.$theme['borderwidth'].'" cellpadding="'.$theme['tablespace'].'" class="tborder" style="display: none;" id="latest_threads_show">
            '.$forum_threads_bit.'
        </table>
    </div>
```

### CSS:

```
#latest_threads_link{
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:150px;
}
```

### jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('a[id^="latest_threads_click"]').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#latest_threads_show').stop().slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

What it does is actually the hidden table shows when I click on the link but NOT with slidding animation, it just shows like poping up into the page. Also the link jumps onto the top (rather then positioning on the same `bottom: 150px`)

Please help

Comment: `slideToggle` animates the height of the element! From 0 to actual height and vice versa.

Comment: ok so what should I've to use then?

Comment: I guess you will have to use `.animate({left:...})`.

Comment: I used `$('#latest_threads_show').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);` but it didn't worked as expected.

Comment: Oh, that worked at all? I guess you cannot just give `toggle`, you have to give an integer, which will `px` have automatically added, or you have to do `'10em'`for example.

Comment: maybe something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4NkL7/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do the sliding animations is to use the additional functionality of show/hide in jQuery UI.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function (){
        $("#show").show('slide',{direction:'left'},1500);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rjzJp/